# Is it true that $Int(A') = cl(A)' ?$

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that $Int(A') = cl(A)' ?$

The actual question was -

Show that $Int(A') = \bar{A}'$ is true for any subset $A$ of a topological space.

I'm not really interested in proof, but I've this doubt, that interior of a set is always open ( also closed if it is $R$ or empty) and derived set and closure are always closed.

So how can be the above statement be true$?$
May be I'm missing some concept.

Comment: I think $A'$, in this case, refers to the complement of $A$.

Comment: This is true if $A'$ stands for the complement of $A$ , but it is not true if $A'$ is the derived set. May be you are mis-interpreting the notation.

Comment: In most of the problems complement of $A$ is denoted by $A^{c}$ and derived set, by $A'$. That's why I was confused. Thanks for helping! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is true! Let's prove it!

**Proposition 1:** Let $A$ be a subset of some topological space $X$. Some $x \ \in \ X$ is in $\bar{A}$ if and only if every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ intersects $A$.

**Proof**

Let us assume that there exists a neighbourhood of $x$ that is disjoint from $A$, which we will call $V$. Well then $X \ - \ V$ is a closed set of $X$ that contains $A$ but does not contain $x$. Therefore, if $x \ \in \ \bar{A}$, then it follows that every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$.

Conversely, let us assume that $x \notin \bar{A}$. Well, $\bar{A}$ is a closed set itself, and $x \ \in \ X \ - \ \bar{A}$, which is open. This means that $x$ has a neighbourhood that does not intersect $A$. Thus, it follows that if every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$, then $x$ must be in $\bar{A}$.

**Proposition 2:** For some subset $A$ in some topological space $X$, $\text{Int}(X \ - \ A) \ = \ X \ - \ \bar{A}$

We will show inclusion both ways. Let $x$ be in $X \ - \ \bar{A}$. It follows that $x$ is in some neighbourhood $V$ that does not intersect $A$. Since the interior of $X \ - \ A$ is simply the union of all open sets contained within $X \ - \ A$, and as we just showed, $x \ \in \ V$ with $V$ disjoint from $A$, therefore completely contained in $X \ - \ A$, it follows that $x \ \in \ \text{Int}(X \ - \ A)$.

Now, let $x \ \in \ \text{Int}(X \ - \ A)$. This means $x$ is in an open set disjoint from $U$ (the interior itself), which implies that $x \ \notin \ \bar{A}$, and is therefore in $X \ - \ \bar{A}$.

Therefore, we have shown that the two sets are equal: $\text{Int}(X \ - \ A) \ = \ X \ - \ \bar{A}. \ \blacksquare$

**Edit**

I'm assuming $A' \ = \ X \ - \ A$. If not, then obviously this proof is misplaced.